# jhipster Unable to change spring run profile to prod - always starts with dev,swagger - Maven as Service

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jhipster, pom.xml, profile

I am doing

```
./mvnw -Pprod clean verify
```

And starts as dev and not has prod profile.

Do I have to change something in my pom file?

```
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>target/classes/static/</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

---

To set as a service in a debian server I do:

```
sudo chmod +x /var/lib/nms-api/n2.jar
sudo chown nmsapi:nmsapi /var/lib/nms-api/n1.jar
sudo ln -s /var/lib/nms-api/n2.jar /etc/init.d/nms2
sudo systemctl enable nms2
sudo service nms2 start
```

**Edit**

I am using jhipster 
framework https://www.jhipster.tech/production/ they say:

> Please note that this JAR file uses the profile we selected when
>   building it. As it was built using the prod file in the previous
>   section, it will therefore run with the prod profile.

and the `ps -aux`  says:

```
/usr/bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar /var/lib/nms-api/n1.jar
```

Is there a way to set `java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod` in the line above when staring as a service?

**Edit 2**

I set the **Environment Variable**

```
sudo -i
root@nms-cp01-vm01:~# export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

and

```
 cat /etc/environment 
$ sudo vi /etc/environment 
$ echo $SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
prod
$ sudo echo $SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
prod
```

And can run in prod profile if

```
 /usr/bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar /var/lib/nms-api/n4test.jar
```

and not in prod profile, but in dev if run as root

```
sudo /usr/bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar /var/lib/nms-api/n4test.jar
```

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -P prod`

Comment: A JAR can not be set as a service you have to have service control file which does not look like this (it is needed to [support systemd service](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.unit.5.en.html)). Just making a jar file executable will not work

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise. The same app I was able to set as service with prod profile here:  https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/ . I did lot of changes and  lot's of commits and after compiling with ./mvnw -Pprod clean verify and setting as a service in the same way I am not able to set as a prod profile only dev profile here https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8040/

Comment: As already mentioned in the given answer it looks like you are mixing maven profiles with spring-boot profiles...

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing maven profiles and spring boot profiles. They are two totally separate concepts. Maven profiles are flags for turning on specific steps during building , whereas a spring profile is a runtime flag to tell spring which set of configuration to apply. For mor information on spring profiles you can [see here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Spring profiles can be set through systen properties, environment variables, but also part of your maven build. The first two are much more flexible imo.

**System properties**

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

**Environmebt Variables**

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

**As Part of a Maven Build profile**

```xml
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
        <!-- The rest of your profile here -->
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        ...
        </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: Thank you @Patrick Magee. So How do you suggest in  jhipster framework https://www.jhipster.tech/production/  I set the prod profile? Weeks ago I only have to do -Pprod and now doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Inês Gomes I updated my answer. I forgot to add one part to the pom.xml. you should just be able to run the maven build with the prod profile and it should now work with Jhiptser

Comment: The Environment Variables were a great suggestion. I did 'export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod' and if I run as root starts dev mode. But if I run as not root starts with prod !!! How can I set the Environment Variables for root? (I did all the pom changes and nothing ...)